# Asp.net web api json interraction

Tags: asp.net, json, azure, asp.net-web-api

Hi there i am developing an azure web api and my put method is below

```
  public string[] Put(SampleRequest request)
        {

            //Getting Request initials
            string[] filmNames = request.Inputs.FilmIds;
            int userAge = request.Inputs.UserAge;
            char userGender = request.Inputs.UserGender;
            int userId = request.Inputs.UserId;
            .
            .
            . Doesnt matter rest of them...
```

When i tried to communicate with json  the request(which is a SampleRequest object) in my put method is getting null so that i cannot parse it to get the data in it, what would be the problem ? My data model,help page json format and my json request(which is in another app) is below

```
public class SampleRequest
    {
        public InputsRequest Inputs { get; set; }
    }

    public class InputsRequest
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int UserAge { get; set; }
        public char UserGender { get; set; }
        public string[] FilmIds { get; set; }
    }
```

application/json, text/json [ API HELP PAGE ]

```
Sample:
{
  "Inputs": {
    "UserId": 1,
    "UserAge": 2,
    "UserGender": "A",
    "FilmIds": [
      "sample string 1",
      "sample string 2"
    ]
  }
}
```

my request from other app:

```
      var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:5291/api/values");
      httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
      httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

      var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
      string json = "{"+"\"Inputs\""+":"+"{"+ "\"UserId\"" + ":" + "12345" + "," 
                                    + "\"UserAge\"" + ":" + "23" + "," 
                                    + "\"UserGender\"" + ":" + "\"M\"" + "," 
                                    + "\"FilmIds\"" + ":" + 
"[\"Kung Fu Panda\",\"I Am Legend\",\"I Am Number Four\"]"+
                                    "}"+"}";

      streamWriter.Write(json);

      var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
      using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
      {
      var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
      }
```

Quick Note: Yes i know the name is FilmIds but i am getting Film names :D dont worry about it

Answer (score 0):

This problem is coming from async methods , the reason behind getting null from put function is that the test application is not sending all of its messages so that the put method gets nothing , solution is using Putasync method below

```
 using (var htc = new HttpClient())
            {
                var res = await htc.PutAsync("http://localhost:5291/api/values", new StringContent(serializedObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            }
```